# Combine a boolean condition with a Where clause in same query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to see if I can somehow reduce the length of this query.
I have a common part with the string.Compare(...),

is IsProperty == true I would like to take all strings where Value is property, and false do the opposite.

What I have now is:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> Groups = 
    isProperty ? model.Groups.Where(
      m => string.Compare(m.Value, "properties", true) == 0
    ).ToList() : 
    model.Groups.Where(
      m => string.Compare(m.Value, "properties", true) != 0
    ).ToList();
```

What I would like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> Groups = 
    model.Groups.Where(
      m => string.Compare(m.Value, "properties", true) == 0 || !=0 //depending on isProperty
    ).ToList();
```

Not sure if it is all possible. (What I really want is to add it to the .Where when I pull values from DB)

Comment: You can just compare the result of `string.Compare(m.Value, "properties", true) == 0` to `isProperty`: `.Where(m => (string.Compare(m.Value, "properties", true) == 0) == isProperty)`. It isn't necessarily the most readable piece of code ever, but that's mostly down to the ugliness of comparing to `0` in the first place.

Comment: @VisualMelon yeah kinda ugly :P replacing to Equal helps?

Comment: Yeah, that certainly looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking @VisualMelon's advice,

I converted it to this code, also replacing the compare with equal, maybe better.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> Groups = 
model.Groups.Where(
  m => string.Equals(m.Value, 
                     "properties", 
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == isProperty)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `var`? `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` looks ugly... Also `Groups` is just local variable, it is common that name starts with lowercase letter in this case.

Comment: This is just part of the code, I didn't use var to you'd know the type of the result. The actual use is only for the .Where (I'm adding this onto a more complicated query) @Maxim

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are going to do there is one more *alternative* so in case you would execute both queries anyway you could use `ToLookup`:

```
var properties = 
    model
        .Groups
        .ToLookup(m => string.Equals(m.Value, "properties", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

this will virtually group your `KeyValuePair<int,string>` by this condition and you can then access them easily via:

```
properties[isProperty]
```

If the key is not available the indexer will return an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some extension to EF, i use something like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
        return source;
    }

    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIfElse<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicateTrue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicateFalse)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return source.Where(predicateTrue);
        }
        else
        {
            return source.Where(predicateFalse);
        }
    }
```